# CSS - positioning a scroll div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scrolls">
<img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" />aruturek
<img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" />aruturek
<img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" />aruturek
<img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" />aruturek
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { 
    background:#EFEFEF; 
    margin: auto; 
    ;
    text-align: center; 
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    width: 540px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.scrolls { 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 150px;
white-space:nowrap
} 
.imageDiv img { 
    margin: 2px;
    max-height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

This is the result:
[qshg7muq9vam.png http://jsfiddle.net/masgp4fg/](http://jsfiddle.net/masgp4fg/)
But I want to text "aruturek" was under the image, and is centered.

```
______________
|             |
|             |
|     HEAD    |    and more...
|             |
|             |
______________
     NICK
```

How I can position this?

Sorry for my english, I am from Poland! D:

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/masgp4fg/

Comment: You're outcome is not a link. Moreover, can you make a JSfiddle please? It would make our lives a lot easier :)

Comment: To me, it is not very clear what you are asking (your image does not show). Can you recreate the issue on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css:

```
.wrapper { 
    background:#EFEFEF; 
    margin: auto; 
    ;
    text-align: center; 
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    width: 540px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.scrolls { 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 150px;
white-space:nowrap
}
.scrolls div{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
.imageDiv img { 
    margin: 2px;
    max-height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

And this html:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scrolls">
  <div>
    <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" /><br>aruturek
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" /><br>aruturek
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" /><br>aruturek
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" /><br>aruturek
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

JSfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/btz4sfsr/

Answer (score 0):

You can update your html and css as per the below fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/v859mz30/

```
.scrolls .imagediv { 
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your english is much better than my Polish

Just make a div for your images and the description.

```
<style>
 .avatar {text-align:center;}
 .avatarname {}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="scrolls">
  <div class="avatar">      
   <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" />
   <div class="avatarname">
     aruturek
   </div>
  </div>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Put your image and name in a div floating left, and add a `br` between `img` and name :

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scrolls">
      <div class="one-avatar">
          <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" /><br/>aruturek
      </div>
      <div class="one-avatar">
          <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" /><br/>aruturek
      </div>
      <div class="one-avatar">
          <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" /><br/>aruturek
      </div>
      <div class="one-avatar">
          <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" /><br/>aruturek
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS (add this class):

```
.one-avatar {
    float:left;
}
```

JSFIDDLE UPDATED : http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/masgp4fg/3/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
.wrapper {
    background:#EFEFEF;
    margin: auto;
    ;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    width: 540px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.scrolls {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 150px;
    white-space:nowrap
}

.cont {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="scrolls">
        <div class="cont">
            <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" />
            <div class="lbl">aruturek</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" />
            <div class="lbl">aruturek</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" />
            <div class="lbl">aruturek</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
            <img src="http://avatar.hivemc.com/avatar/aruturek/100" />
            <div class="lbl">aruturek</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```